# How to return a Single DataTable From All Excel Sheets Using Interop.Excel Library

Tags: c#

How to Return a Single Data Table from All Excel Sheet, I have wrote all the code for this Method but when more than one sheet its read then the data from 2nd, 3rd and so on sheet it is inserted into the 1st sheet Columns. Please correct this problem it will help a lot of people who want to read all the excel sheet using interop.excel COM which is very nice tool because ado.net reading creating problems of Version Compatibility issues.

```
public System.Data.DataTable SetOne(string ExcelFilePath)
{       
    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
           Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
           Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
           Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            int NoOfSheetRows=0;
    foreach (Worksheet item in app.Worksheets)
    {
        string sheetname = item.Name;
        Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)wb.Sheets[sheetname];

        Range excelRange = sheet.UsedRange;
        string fileRange = sheet.UsedRange.Address;
        string filecolums = fileRange.Substring(6, 1);
        List<string> str = new List<string>();
        int cntr = 0;

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range row in excelRange.Rows)
        {
            int rowNumber = row.Row;
            string[] A4D4 = this.GetRange("A" + rowNumber + ":" + filecolums + "" + rowNumber + "", sheet);

            if (rowNumber.Equals(1))
            {
                foreach (var itm in A4D4)
                {
                    if (table.Columns.Contains(itm)==false)
                    {
                        table.Columns.Add(itm);
                        str.Add(itm);
                        cntr++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        table.Columns.Add(itm + "..");
                        str.Add(itm);
                        cntr++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DataRow drow;
                drow = table.NewRow();
                drow.ItemArray = A4D4;
               //table.Rows.InsertAt(drow, NoOfSheetRows);
                table.Rows.Add(drow); // This is Area where the Problem is created the the sheet 2,3,4 and so forth data is inserted to 1st Sheet Columns 
            }
        }
        NoOfSheetRows += cntr;
    }
    return table;
}

public string[] GetRange(string range, Worksheet excelWorksheet)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range workingRangeCells =
      excelWorksheet.get_Range(range, Type.Missing);
    System.Array array = (System.Array)workingRangeCells.Cells.Value2;
    string[] arrayS = array.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
    return arrayS;
}
```

Comment: The use of interop.excel mean that you have installed microsoft excel on the web server (for example). Microsoft tell that microsoft office cannot be used in serverside, it is not designed for it (it crash, consume much memory and freeze the application pool).

Comment: For god's sake STOP using Interop for such operations. You don't use a hammer to plough a field and using interop on a web server is even more WRONG.
Use a library like EPPLUS, aspose.cells (xls support) or one of the bazillion other libraries.

Comment: @bdn02  I am using this for the Desktop Application nor for Web so there  is no need of web server . So Interop is good for Stand alone system as compared to ado.net which creating compatibility issues.But however My problem is only to to Organize the Data in DataTable as I have Already Read the data from the Excel sheet the File have .@Christian Sauer am i wrong

Comment: @Shakir.iti Interop ist 'better' than Ado.Net, in as much as one stump is better than no leg. A library like EPPLUS is magnitudes faster (factor 1000 is possible), much easier to develop and don't suffer from sporadic errors like excel kliing itself.

Comment: @Christian Sauer I tried the EPPlus, this is very nice dll which i have used to convert all my Excel File Data to a DataTable for which i spent many time in Excel.Interop . Please Add your Question I want to Make it Mark Answer that other Guys could help from your Question . nice tool EPPlust ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend EPPLUS - it's a library designed to read / write xlsx / xlsm files. It's very fast, free and much more robust than Interop.